# Почему функция не дожидается завершения работы другой функции NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Не могу понять.

Вот есть функция, которая через 5 сек возвращает хеллоу

```
    function sayHello(){
               setTimeout(() => {
               var data='hello'
               return data;         
            }, 5000)
    }

    module.exports = sayHello;
```

В другой функции хочу это вывести,

```
const getHello = require('../DB/remote/methods-api/getPopularProduct') // тут getHello() = sayHello()

 async function viewHello() {
      console.log("await "+ await getHello());
}
```

но выводит всегда undefined. Пробовал промисами, тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас тут небольшая путаница:

1. `sayHello()` через 5 секунд не возвращает `'hello'`. Она устанавливает таймаут и тут же возвращает `undefined`, который и получает функция в импортирующем файле. `'hello'` возвращает фукнция, установленная в таймауте, но возвращает его «в пустоту», потому что возвращённое значение нигде не принимается.
2. Импортируемая функция не возвращает Promise и не является асинхронной, поэтому `await` перед её вызовом не имеет смысла.

Кажется, то, чего вы пытаетесь добиться, можно реализовать так:

```js
function sayHello() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = 'hello';
      resolve(data);
    }, 5000);
  });
}

module.exports = sayHello;
```

```js
const getHello = require('./module.js');

async function viewHello() {
  console.log("await " + await getHello());
}

viewHello();
```

Comment: Боже, спасибо! Получается, что нужно в одной функции сделать обещание, а во второй ждать обещанного с помощью await. А вот вопрос ещё, а та функция, которая ждёт обещанного она обязательно всегда должна быть асинхронной или можно её как-то сделать обычной синхронной?

Comment: Если она ждёт обещанного с помощью `await`, то она может быть только `async`, иначе будет синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: А ждать можно только через await? Или есть ещё какие-нибудь варианты, что бы привести к синхронности? Просто я боюсь, что может возникнуть целая цепочка из асинхронных функций в дальнейшем, это будет непредсказуемое поведение в коде.

Comment: В таких случаях обычно говорят, что асинхронность заразна — если уж вы зацепили что-то асинхронное, в синхронное вам обратно не вернуться. Так что вам остаётся выбирать между цепочками колбеков, цепочками промисов (то есть цепочками `.then()`) или последовательностью `await` в асинхронной функции. Последнее не так уж сложно и непредсказуемо, если приноровиться —  разобраться в теории и набить руку.

Comment: Тут ещё, конечно, играет роль, насколько поддерживаются промисы в API, с которым вы работаете. Если оно достаточно современно и «промисифицировано», то всё просто, знай проставляй себе `await`, где нужно. А если оно немного устаревшее, тогда вам придётся то и дело создавать вспомогательные обёртки из промисов, если захотите всё свести к одному стилю.